# Creating Huge Sparse Matrices in python

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix, physics

I have been using normal matrices from numpy to store a Matrix for a physics project. The size of the matrix is determined by the physical system. 
So for instance if the system has parameters:
L=4 and N =2, then the matrix is of dimension 4C2 = 6, so the matrix is a 6x6 matrix.

This is fine except for now I need larger size i.e 20C10 = 184,756. So the matrix required is now a 184756x184756 matrix, which when I try to create an empty matrix of this size gives me a memory error. (with 16GB of RAM)

The resultant matrix is mostly just diagonal and off diagonal terms, so there are a huge amount of zeroes in the large size matrices. Hence Sparse Matrices seem like the correct approach.

I have tried to get it to work by looking at other answers and just trying by myself from the python libraries, but to no avail.

Below is the code for my normal matrix:

```
def HamGen(L,N,delta,J):
    """
    Will Generate the hamiltonian matrix, 
    Takes parameters:
        L : Number of sites
        N : Number of spin downs
        delta : anistropy 

    Each term is gotten by getting H(i,j) = <Set(i)|H|Set(j)>
    The term will be a number
    Where H is an operator that acts on elements of the set 
    """
    D = BS.dimension(L,N) # Gets the dimension of the matrix, i.e NxN matrix
    Hamiltonian = np.zeros((D,D)) # Creates empty matrix 

    count1 = 0
    Set = BS.getSet(L,N) # The set of states to construct the hamiltonian

    for alpha in Set: #loop through the set (i)
        count2 = 0
        for beta in Set: # j
            """
            Compute ab = <alpha|Hamiltonian|beta>
            Then let Hamiltonian[a][b] = ab                        
            """
            if (alpha == beta):
                for i in range(L-1):
                    # Sz is just a function
                    Hamiltonian[count1][count2] += (J*delta*Sz(beta,i)*Sz(beta,i+1))
            b = check(alpha,beta)
            if b:
                del b[0]
                for j in b:
                    Hamiltonian[count1][count2] += (J*0.5*(Sp(beta,j)*Sm(beta,j+1) + Sm(beta,j)*Sp(beta,j+1)))
            count2 += 1
        count1 += 1
    return (np.asmatrix(Hamiltonian))
```

I mostly just need to know how to make the matrix without having to use as much memory, and then how to put the terms I calculate into the matrix.

Here is my attempt to make the matrix as a sparse matrix.

```
def SPHamGen(L,N,delta):
"""
Will Generate the hamiltonian matrix, 
Takes parameters:
    L : Number of sites
    N : Number of spin downs
    delta : anistropy 
"""
start = timeit.default_timer()

D = BS.dimension(L,N)
Ham = sp.coo_matrix((D,D))
print Ham
#data = ([0])*D

count1 = 0
Set = BS.getSet(L,N)


data = ([0])*(D*D)
rows = ([0])*(D*D)
cols = ([0])*(D*D)
for alpha in Set:
    count2 = 0
    for beta in Set:
        """
        Compute ab = <alpha|Hamiltonian|beta>
        Then let Hamiltonian[a][b] = ab                        
        """
        if (alpha == beta):
            for i in range(L-1):
                #Hamiltonian[count1][count2] += (J*delta*Sz(beta,i)*Sz(beta,i+1))
                data[count2] += (J*delta*Sz(beta,i)*Sz(beta,i+1)) 
            rows[count2] = count1
            cols[count2] = count2
        b = check(alpha,beta)
        if b:
            del b[0]
            for j in b:
                #Hamiltonian[count1][count2] += (J*0.5*(Sp(beta,j)*Sm(beta,j+1) + Sm(beta,j)*Sp(beta,j+1)))
                data[count2] += (J*0.5*(Sp(beta,j)*Sm(beta,j+1) + Sm(beta,j)*Sp(beta,j+1)))
            rows[count2] = count1
            cols[count2] = count2
        count2 += 1
    count1 += 1
    Ham = Ham + sp.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)), shape = (D,D))

time = (timeit.default_timer() - start)
print "\n"+str(time) +"s to calculate H"
#return Ham   
return sparse.csr_matrix(Ham)
```

Thanks, Phil.

Comment: Your code seems to create a dense matrix and then transforms to sparse. If you got not enough memory to hold the dense version, that's obviously a problem. Don't start with a dense matrix. Start with sparse data-structures and chose the correct ones which work for your problem / access pattern. E.g. create a coo_matrix; fill and then transform to something which helps in your case, maybe csr, maybe csc, or something else.

Comment: Thats what I need help with, I have tried making a sparse matrix and filling it in a similar way, however i still needed huge arrays to store my data in before putting them in the sparse matrix, and also when i made the matrix for small Dimensions I got the incorrect matrix

Comment: Then reduce your example to a minimal one and show your failed attempts. I can't imagine what's going wrong.

Comment: Posted an update with my (failed) attempt

Comment: Without further analyzing: your usage of coo_matrix is probably not a good idea! Did you not read the docs? [readme](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix). Ham = Ham + coo_matrix is not a good idea. I also think the remaining code is strange, but well... to big to analyze... When using coo, i don't know when i would use the internal-storage format directly (what you seem to do).

Comment: Do you mean I used it poorly, or that it was a poor choice to use coo_matrix over csc etc.

Comment: ```Disadvantages of the COO format: does not directly support: arithmetic operations, slicing```. But that's probably not the only problem of your code (and i would maby expect an warning from scipy). I recommend starting way more simple and when observing memory problems, observing nnz_count frequently. If there would be an error, then your iterative matrix + matrix almost surely asks for a dense-matrix.

Comment: So what format would you recommend I use

Comment: I don't know your access patterns and the code is not that self-explaining (i even think it's much more complicated than it needs to be; but it's just a guess). So no recommendation from me (except for what i already said: frequently check nnz_count; there are  probably more nnz's introduced than you think).

Comment: In the normal matrix version, I have a nested loop, that goes through an array, and it uses a function on the values given and returns a number, I then put the number into the matrix. but most of the time this number is zero when the dimension is large. So I just need to know how to make a suitable sparse matrix, and how to input these numbers i calculate into the matrix.

Comment: Then start by thinking about why you put that Ham += mat in the sparse-version, which is not in the dense-version. Again, too lazy to check your code. But if all your ops are just some_index += val, then just use coo_matrix and do that op. Don't access the internal-format, just index like a dense matrix. So just for a start: take your dense-version and just replace the dense-matrix with coo_matrix. **Edit:** although your dense-matrix indexing looks wrong and i don't even know what that code will do. (my_np_matrix_2d[a, b] is indexed like that)

Comment: Forget about the operators for now, suppose I just want to make a matrix(M), where M(i,j) is given by a function of i and j. How do I create a sparse matrix, and put these values in the correct position in this matrix.

Comment: scipy.sparse has an matrix-interface. So i think you know how to access an matrix, right? So what's the problem? Did you read any docs? The only thing which matters here in your simple example: what does this function do? If it outputs random-values, every cell will be filled. If it output randomly 1's and 0's one need to be either filtering unnecessary addings of 0 (as implicitly stored already) or be careful about the storage (not sure what scipy does in terms of explicit 0's). Calling func on N*M occasions might introduce futher trouble (complexity-wise).

Comment: The function will return mostly zeros, except near and on the diagonal, so when it gets f(10,10)= 0.5 say, then how does one put this in the sparse matrix

Comment: Then keep it simple: ```mat = sp.dok_matrix((10000,10000))```. Add your item: ```mat[10,10] = 0.5```. Check content: ```print(mat)``` -> ```<10000x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 1 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>```. You probably want to convert this dok_matrix to some other format *after your construction*. But without knowing what you want to do, this decision is hard. Why *dok_matrix* here: ```Allows for efficient O(1) access of individual elements. Duplicates are not allowed. Can be efficiently converted to a coo_matrix once constructed.```

Comment: Muchos Gracias, and then I should convert the dok matrix to a csc matrix or csr, for performing mathematical operations on it etc.?

Comment: Yes! Check the docs on which storage allows which ops efficiently. Those conversions are cheap (linear in number of nnz's).

Comment: Great, I shall use CSR as thats what I was simply casting the normal matrix to with `sparse.csr_matrix(H)`