# How to create huge sparse matrix with dtype=float16?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I've tried all of these and had either memory error or some kind of other error.

```
Matrix1 = csc_matrix((130000,130000)).todense()

Matrix1 = csc_matrix((130000,130000), dtype=float_).todense()

Matrix1 = csc_matrix((130000,130000), dtype=float16).todense()
```

How can I create a huge sparse matrix with float type of data?

Comment: It looks like you're successfully creating a huge sparse matrix—and then immediately calling `todense()` on it, which is what causes the memory error. If you want a sparse array, why are you converting it to a dense array?

Comment: Also, `float_` is an alias for `float64`, so why would you use that if you want `float16`? That's obviously going to make it take 4x as much RAM.

Comment: does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349470/creating-huge-sparse-matrices-in-python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a huge sparse matrix, just do exactly what you're doing:

```
Matrix1 = csc_matrix((130000,130000), dtype=float16)
```

… without calling [`todense()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.todense.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.todense) at the end. This succeeds, and takes a tiny amount of memory.<sup>1</sup>

When you add `todense()`, that successfully creates a huge sparse array that takes a tiny amount of memory, and then tries to convert that to a dense array that takes a huge amount of memory, which fails with a `MemoryError`. But the solution to that is just… don't do that.

And likewise, if you use [`dtype=float_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) instead of `dtype=float16`, you get float64 values (which aren't what you want, and take 4x the memory), but again, the solution is just… don't do that.

---

<sub>1. `sys.getsizeof(m)` gives 56 bytes for the sparse array handle, `sys.getsizeof(m.data)` gives 96 bytes for the internal storage handle, and `m.data.nbytes` gives 0 bytes for the actual storage, for a grand total of 152 bytes. Which is unlikely to raise a `MemoryError`.</sub>